# Storing individual answers from loop into an array

Tags: matlab

I have a loop which provides a value, through each interation the value changes. Is there a way of storing the value at each point into an array, so rather than having 10 individual results outputted I could have a 1 x 10 array storing these values ?

Comment: what do you call a "value"? A single number? An arbitrary matrix? A list of strings?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes:

```
a = zeros(10,1);

for ii = 1:10
   a(ii) = your_calc(x,y);
end
```